# How to set condition by referring whether specific record exists or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following `mst_table` and `history_record`

`mst_table`

```
document name
1        Request for Approval
2        Purchase order
3        Payment Slip
・　　　　・
・　　　　・
```

`history_record`

```
case date        status
A     2023/3/13   rejected
A     2023/3/14   rejected
A     2023/3/15   approved
B     2023/3/13   rejected
B     2023/3/13   rejected
```

I would like to get appropriate document date from `mst_table` referring to `case` as variable in `history_record`

When they have `approved`,I don't need document `A` `Request for Approval`.
When `case =A` was set as variable. my desired result is

```
document name
2        Purchase order
3        Payment Slip
・　　　　・
・　　　　・
```

when `case=B` was set, my desired result is like follows

```
document name
1        Request for Approval
2        Purchase order
3        Payment Slip
・　　　　・
・　　　　・
```

I tried like follows. but

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM history_record WHERE case = 'A')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use exists logic as follows:

```sql
SELECT m.document, m.name
FROM mst_table m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM history_record h
    WHERE h."case" = m.document AND
          h.status = 'approved'
          -- AND h."case" = 'A'
);
```

You may restrict the exists clause to a specific document, if you want the exclusion to apply at a document level.

Comment: thank you for answer ! in fact, each key has no relation in my sample. so that I would like to eliminate `document = 1` when some case has `approved` in my `mst_table`. sorry for inconvenience..

Comment: There needs to be a correlation between the two tables, otherwise your question cannot be answered.